# Customising a RegExp for international phone numbers

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression that matches most phone numbers:

```
^((\+|00)[1-9]{1,3})?(\-| {0,1})?(([\d]{0,3})(\-| {0,1})?([\d]{5,11})){1}$
```

It is fine with phone numbers like:

- +39123456789
- +39-123-456789
- +39 123 456789

And a combinations of spaces, hyphens and no-spaces, like:

- +39 123456789
- +39-123 456789

Now, I need two things:

1. Allow the dot as separator too, like this:

   - +39.123.456789
   - +39 123.456789
   - +39-123.456789
2. Don't allow more than one separator between numbers. At the moment, the regex allows a poorly formatted string, e.g.:

   - +39- 123456789

Comment: 4 min late - Need to be faster. Got result in another way  : https://regex101.com/r/eW6eA8/1

Comment: Falt4rm, your answer was pretty fine and it worked better that the first solution from stribizhev!!! Never give up! :-)

Comment: Well Glad it helped - Regex Ftw ! --> "Only Ladder Is real" - GoT // Or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixing your regex, I can suggest the following regex:

```
^(?![^ .-]*[ .-]{2})((\+|00)[1-9]{1,3})?[ .-]?((\d{0,3})[ .-]?(\d{5,11}))$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ0dI5/3)

**EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?![^ .-]*[ .-]{2})` - Making sure there are no subsequent separators
- `((\+|00)[1-9]{1,3})?` - Prefix `+` or `00` and 1 or 3 digits from 1-9 range
- `[ .-]?` - Optinal separator
- `((\d{0,3})[ .-]?(\d{5,11}))` - 0 to 3 digits followed by an optional separator and then 5 to 11 digits
- `$` - End of string.

In case you do not make use of the capturing groups here, just remove them or make non-capturing:

```
^(?![^ .-]*[ .-]{2})(?:(?:\+|00)[1-9]{1,3})?[ .-]?\d{0,3}[ .-]?\d{5,11}$
```

Following your logic, we can further optimize this pattern as

```
^(?:\+|00)[1-9]{1,3}[. -]?[0-9]{3}[. -]?[0-9]{5,11}$
```

It is an [improved version suggested by @Falt4rm](https://regex101.com/r/eW6eA8/2) in the comment.

Comment: Thanks, the upate works better (in the prevous version a valid phone number as +393491234567 was rejected)